# Spring boot authentication issue?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, gcloud

**As you can see on** :  http://website-live-245110.appspot.com/ (gccloud hosted site) following the code logic, any username with 4 characters should be able to log in. Although this is not the case at the moment and i have trouble understanding why.
You should try logging in multiple times to grasp the issue.

CustomAuthenticationProvider.java

```java
package com.spring.authprovider;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationProvider;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.core.AuthenticationException;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class CustomAuthenticationProvider implements AuthenticationProvider{

    @Autowired
    private ThirdPartyAuthProviderClient thirdPartyAuthProviderClient;

    // one a user logs in, the authentication variable is filled with the details of the authentication
    @Override
    public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {
        // when the user logs in to the application, our object will be filled by spring
        String name = authentication.getName();
        Object password = authentication.getCredentials(); //object that encapsulates password that user types 
        // not printing or storing password anyone

        if(thirdPartyAuthProviderClient.shouldAuthenticate(name,password)) {
            // the array list is for roles, because we are not using it now, we are sending it an empty one
            return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(name, password, new ArrayList<>());
        } else {
            System.out.println("authentication failed for user: " + name);
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<?> authentication) {
        // there are multiple ways of authentication, use use username and password
        return authentication.equals(UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.class);
    }

}
```

ThirdPartyAuthProviderClient.java

```java
package com.spring.authprovider;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class ThirdPartyAuthProviderClient {

    //emulates request to third party application
    public boolean shouldAuthenticate(String username, Object password) {
        // 3rd party request to see if user is correct or no or should be logged in
        // user with username with 4 digits can be logged in to the application
        return username.length() == 4;
    }

}
```

WebSecurityConfig.java

```java
package com.spring;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.EnableGlobalMethodSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.WebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.provisioning.InMemoryUserDetailsManager;

import com.spring.authprovider.CustomAuthenticationProvider;



@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private CustomAuthenticationProvider authProvider;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/", "/home", "/time").permitAll() // any request matching /, /home, /time
                                                                                // can be accessed by anyone
                .anyRequest().authenticated() // any other request needs to be authenticated
                .and().authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/admin/**") // only admin can access /admin/anything
                .hasRole("ADMIN")
                .and().formLogin().loginPage("/login") // permit all to form login--- we use loginPage to use custom page
                .permitAll()
                .and().logout() // permit all to form logout
                .permitAll();

    }


    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        //specify auth provider
        auth.authenticationProvider(authProvider);
    }

    // configuration of static resources
    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web.ignoring().antMatchers("/templates/**", "/assets/**");
    }
}
```

MvcConfig.java

```java
package com.spring;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ViewControllerRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer;

@Configuration
public class MvcConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addViewController("/home").setViewName("home");
        registry.addViewController("/").setViewName("home");
        registry.addViewController("/hello").setViewName("hello");
        registry.addViewController("/login").setViewName("login");
    }
}
```

**Templates**

hello.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"
      xmlns:sec="http://www.thymeleaf.org/thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity3">
    <head>
        <title>Hello World!</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1 th:inline="text">Hello [[${#httpServletRequest.remoteUser}]]!</h1>
        <form th:action="@{/logout}" method="post">
            <input type="submit" value="Sign Out"/>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

home.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org" xmlns:sec="http://www.thymeleaf.org/thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity3">
    <head>
        <title>Spring Security Example</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Welcome!</h1>

        <p>Click <a th:href="@{/hello}">here</a> to see a greeting.</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

login.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"
      xmlns:sec="http://www.thymeleaf.org/thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity3">
    <head>
        <title>Spring Security Example </title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div th:if="${param.error}">
            Invalid username and password.
        </div>
        <div th:if="${param.logout}">
            You have been logged out.
        </div>
        <form th:action="@{/login}" method="post">
            <div><label> User Name : <input type="text" name="username"/> </label></div>
            <div><label> Password: <input type="password" name="password"/> </label></div>
            <div><input type="submit" value="Sign In"/></div>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

I expect it to either log me in when a username with 4 characters is entered, Or output Invalid username and password. Error. 
Code is here : https://github.com/jeffpascal/Spring-and-springboot/tree/devs/SpringSecurity

Comment: What can you see in the logs? What Java version are you running the project with? I have cloned your project, run locally without modification and it works exactly as it should.

Comment: By any chance, do you have multiple instances / is the instance restarted? AFAIK session is by default stored inmemory.

Comment: helospark, the server is indeed in multiple instances. do you think that is the issue? I just need to figure out how to make it run on one instance. And i know it works locally, that's my issue. The logs : https://pastebin.com/UyBpJprQ . I can see the login api being called but don't understand why my authentication method is ignored.

Comment: And even though it is on multiple instances, shouldn't it just follow the code logic anyway?

Comment: as I saw, it follows your logic, with wrong username, I get the message about invalid username/password, with right username I get a JSESSIONID. However the sessionId->Authentication is stored inmemory, which means, when the page reloaded and another instance serves that requests, it will not know about the session and you again get redirected to the login page (if the servers are in round-robin, I would imagine you could never get actually log in, as each server overrides the JSESSIONID to the one it stores in memory).

Comment: With multiple instance, you probably need to store the session in DB or use stateless auth (ex. JWT)

Comment: I see what you mean. Will try .